# pybind11::error_already_set at memory location (Exception)

Tags: c++, python-3.x, exception, visual-studio-2017, pybind11

I am trying to Call a python function from C++ VS 2017 but I am getting an exception.

[image]

I used Cmake to compile pybind11 in VS2017 . I included the headers but I had to link python separately[image]

( I used Cmake to compile pybind11 in VS2017 . I included the headers but I had to link python separately)

**Python function :**

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen, rosen_der 
def min_rosen(x0): 
    res = minimize(rosen, x0) 
    return res
```

I used pyInstaller to create .exe file `pyinstaller --onefile min_rosen.py`

**C++ Call :**

```
py::scoped_interpreter guard{}; 
py::function min_rosen =
       py::reinterpret_borrow<py::function>(py::module::import("min_rosen.exe").attr("min_rosen");

py::object result = min_rosen(std::vector<double>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the return result of `py::module::import("min_rosen.exe")`: it's most likely nullptr. Use `PyErr_Print()` to get a proper diagnostics message.

Comment: Thank you. I will  try it and update  my question.

Comment: @WimLavrijsen Thanks a lot man, this was the issue for me. the way i was importing my module (from my package) was wrong. fixing that solved this error. really appreciate dit

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem when I tried to import a python module written by me. In my case, it worked when I put the python file to my solution folder, current working direcory. I think this problem came from python module location.